# Android Video View Size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview

I am trying to set custom height and width of the video view inside a Relative Layout in the center, top and bottom contains other layouts. What the problem i am facing is the video view is not picking the size in width and height i am providing. It shows its video size may be but i want it to show exactly the size i am setting. I am placing the Video View in xml layout, so if there is any work around or i am missing something please guide me on that. Here is the layout tags below

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="640dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="640dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="640dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp" >

        <VideoView
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: No success with that as well, when i reduce the height the width is also reduced automatically, not the one i am setting.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution for you

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams videoviewlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(newwidth, newheight);
    videoviewlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    videoviewlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    videoview.setLayoutParams(videoviewlp);
    videoview.invalidate();
```

Comment: No success with that as well, when i reduce the height the width is also reduced automatically, not the one i am setting.